# How to create one to one relation while having one to many relation with a model in prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have these two models (User, Question), first I am fetching all the questions that a user have this is working perfectly fine but I want to fetch ever user that created that question so I added user with User type but this is not working.

```
model User {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  username String 
  email String
  password String
  questions Question[] 
  answers String[] @default([])
  reputation Int @default(0)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
}

model Question {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  user User /* this is throwing error of ambiguous relation */
  userId String 
  userQuestionsReference User @relation( fields: [userId], references: [id])
  title String
  bodyText String
  comments String[] @default([])
  upvote String[] @default([])
  downvote String[] @default([])
  acceptedAnswer String @default("")
  views String[] @default([])
  tags String[] @default([])
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
  
}
```

Comment: Solved this by removing the userQuestionReference field and directly putting the reference on user field like - user User @relation( fields: [userId], references: [id])